# TFS Online, change administrator

Tags: tfs, administrator

How do we change the administrator if they are no longer part of the company and no one has Administrator permissions?

Comment: You have some serious management and security issues.

Answer (score 0):

First suggest you double check the users in **Project Collection Administrators group**. You could also check if there are a user is account owner's permission in your company.

Next time, when your team's roles and responsibilities change, **change your VSTS account owner to another user.** This could avoid such situation, how to change the account owner please refer official tutorial-- [Change account owner for VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/change-account-ownership-vs?view=vsts)

For now, if no one has these permissions ([*project collection administrator or account owner permissions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/faq-change-account-ownership?view=vsts#find-owner-pca)) in your company, please **[contact VSTS Support](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/support)**.